# Set duplicate headers in API scan replacer

Tags: owasp, zap

We have the same header in several API requests, however the value is different.

For example:

```
PUBLIC_KEY=value1

PRIVATE_KEY=value2
```

We would need the same header to accept different values for different requests.

Request1:

```
//this would be the authorization config for one of the requests
echo "----> Building prop file:"
echo  "replacer.full_list(0).description=auth1" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(0).enabled=true" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(0).matchtype=REQ_HEADER" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(0).matchstr=Authorization" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(0).regex=false" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(0).replacement=$PUBLIC_KEY" >> auth.prop
```

For request2:

```
//this would apply to another request, but the name of the header would remain the same
echo  "replacer.full_list(1).description=auth1" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(1).enabled=true" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(1).matchtype=REQ_HEADER" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(1).matchstr=Authorization" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(1).regex=false" >> auth.prop
echo  "replacer.full_list(1).replacement=$PRIVATE_KEY" >> auth.prop
```

Is it possible to achieve these different values for header with the same name in different requests in one zap-api-scan.py?

And If so, is it possible to extract some logs during/after execution to see headers and response body?

Answer (score 1):

On what basis do you want to specify different values?
This should be possible with httpsender scripts as long as you have access to all of the information you need.

Comment: I have to extract values from the response. Then, this should be turned into Base64 token and put on several requests as header.
I have several cases like these and still not able to find a solution how to relate one request with specific script.

Comment: ZAP script will be able to handle this, but if you cant work out how the define the criteria then ZAP wont be able to help with that.